# Couchbase Servers Automatically Joining Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, couchbase

I seem to be having an issue where I have several environments running couchbase (TEST/DEV/...) and all the servers seem to be attempting to join each other and I see in logs that they failed to join because they couldn't communicate.  I expect this because we have firewalls between our environments, but my question is how/why do they try and auto join a cluster and how do I stop that.  Has anyone seen this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase does not have the built-in functionality to auto-join nodes in or to a cluster. Unless you tell a node to join with other nodes or vice versa, those nodes operate as standalone. So you would have to have a script or something that is attempting to automate this. Something like Chef, Puppet, shell scripts, whatever.